# Set axis marks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot

```
plt.xlim(xmin=0, xmax=max_value)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

where all values in `x` are between `0` and `max_value`.

It's important for me to have both start value `0` and end value `max_value` on the x-axis in the plot.

If `max_value = 88`, the plot will show labels 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, and 80 but not 88. How can I make sure the plots shows the end value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This use default labels and add `max_value`:

```
plt.xticks(list(plt.xticks()[0]) + [max_value])
```

Comment: If max_value = 88, the plot will show both 0, 10, ..., 88, and 90. 88 and 90 will be stacked and thus impossible to read. but almost good

Comment: Try this: `plt.xticks(list(plt.xticks()[0])[:-1] + [max_value])`

Answer (score 1):

Consider use `plt.xticks` method:

```
x = range(0,100)
y = x
max_value = 88
plt.xlim(xmin=0, xmax=max_value)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xticks([0, 10, max_value/2, max_value])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: but the x values vary so I can't just 'hardcode' some labels

Comment: Correct. I am not really know sure what is you are trying to plot or what is the range of your data, but my guess is that you need to use something like this:
 `plt.xticks(sorted(list(np.arange(0, max_value, 10)) + [max_value]))`